# How to make PHP and C/C++ interact with each other

Tags: php, c++, c

I have the usual PHP and MYSQL server running but I want to perform some CPU intensive computations. Therefore I wish to run a C program to handle that part.

Is it possible to exchange data between a PHP and a C/C++ program on the server itself?

Regards
PP

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152584/is-there-anything-like-pythons-ctype-for-php-accessing-libraries-without-the-n) may answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible and you have multiple ways to achieve that.

- write an extension (as it was already suggested)
- call your C program with 'exec()'
- use [Gearman](http://gearman.org/)
- run C program as a service and communicate with it via pipe or a socket

From the above I would choose an extension or Gearman.

Answer (score 2):

Why not write a C++ program and then use [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) to fetch the results when it is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Write an extension :)

[PHP extension wrapper for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445428/php-extension-wrapper-for-c)

```
#include "php.h"
```