# Is it possible to integrate c++ code in php

Tags: php, c++, opencv

I have done face recognition project in c++(opencv) now i need to integrate my c++ code to php is it possible? how it can be accomplished?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179755/how-to-make-php-and-c-c-interact-with-each-other?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110682/extending-php-with-c

Answer (score 0):

Only if you can compile your code to run on the server in order to execute it from php (ie [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)/[passthru](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)/[shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)/[system](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) etc).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own PHP extension to integrate C++ code and OpenCV into php.
Here is an example: https://github.com/infusion/PHP-Facedetect